# Is obspy able to compute the magnitude of a trace or stream?

Tags: python, magnitude, obspy

Anyone here an expert in obspy?

I'm making a obspy based application that detects earthquakes with intensity 3 above using the magnitude produced. Is it possible to compute the magnitude using obspy?